# What datastructure would you use to represent this format of data?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, data-structures, model

I have to write kind of a complicated query to get some statistics for the rules in our system for each Agency we have in our database.

It looks something like this:

[image]

There will be an arbitrary number of columns (rules) and rows (agencies) for this data. For example, here there are 5 main rule columns shown, but this could just as easily be 1 or 2 columns instead. Each column consists of 3 numbers (Flagged, Percent and Days).  What I can't even get my brain around is what datastructure should I even return from my database to represent this?

Eventually I need to construct something that looks like this in my ASP.NET MVC view, but right now I'm just trying to get the data out of the database and represent it in a logical datastructure that will be easy to work with when constructing this table.

What data structure should I use to represent my tabular data with an arbitrary number of columns/rows?  If you had to return this data out of the database in a LINQ query, what kind of container would you put it in?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about LINQ:

But to represent them in Object Oriented fashion is straight-forward.

Agency -> n-Rules -> Each Rule has attributes

E.g.Rule Object will consist of:

```
class Rule { //Probably you would like to call something more business related
   String ruleName; //E.g. Duplicate Accounts at Same Agency
   int numberOfFlagged; //E.g 4
   int percent; //E.g. 1%
   int days; //E.g. 6
}

class Agency {
   List<Rule> rules;
}
```

Once you have the data loaded you represent in Excel or a View as you want.