# Datastructure to represent a lookup table with "multiple-combined" key

Tags: c++, oop

How will you design a table datastructure for lookup?

I basically have to represent the following table

```
Country             Activity        Legal_Age
European            Drink           18
European            Drive           21
American            Drink           21
American            Drive           18
```

Here my Key is (Country & Activity) and the value is Legal_age.

I thought of using std::map to breakdown this problem (into individual maps) as follows.

national_Activity_age_map

```
European            European_Activity_age_map
American            American_Activity_age_map
```

European_Activity_age_map

```
Drink           18
Drive           21
```

American_Activity_age_map

```
Drink           21
Drive           18
```

But the problem here is, as the number of columns to the original table keeps growing, the number of maps to be added and maintained keeps growing.

Let's say the US chooses to have seperate drinking ages for US-citizens and non-citizens. Then I will have to add new mappings and also modify existing mappings.

Is there a simple & a clean way to represent this data in a DataStructure which takes in a multiple factored Key and produce one value?

There are a few similar questions like below but nothing answers my specific problem.
[What datastructure would you use to represent this format of data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1072574/what-datastructure-would-you-use-to-represent-this-format-of-data)

Update:
I can't use Boost features at work since it has to be ported (or something like that). Is there a C++ (gcc 4.1.2) feature that I can use.

Comment: Would help to say which columns you want to query against.  Also any book on DB schema design would be all about this topic.

Comment: Brian: I mentioned above that my Key is (Country & Activity) and the value is Legal_age.

Comment: map< pair< country, activity > , age >

Comment: Yes, this solves the current problem. But how does it scale when there are more attributes that need to be part of the key(or index)?.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try [Boost Multi-Index](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/libs/multi_index/doc/index.html).

> The Boost Multi-index Containers Library provides a class template named multi_index_container which enables the construction of containers maintaining one or more indices with different sorting and access semantics. Indices provide interfaces similar to those of STL containers, making using them familiar. The concept of multi-indexing over the same collection of elements is borrowed from relational database terminology and allows for the specification of complex data structures in the spirit of multiply indexed relational tables where simple sets and maps are not enough.

Comment: Thanks. But can't use Boost features at work since it has to be ported (or something like that). Is there a C++ (gcc 4.1.2) feature that I can use.

Comment: "Boost.MultiIndex is a header-only library, requiring no additional object modules." So you could just download only the `.hpp` files that you need, and copy them into your project. http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/libs/multi_index/doc/reference/index.html